# i can't get my simple program to pass a 2d array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, 2d

ive tried several ways but i can't get the function "Matrixinputs" to accept the 2d array by reference. "Matrixinputs" is going to change the inputs of the array to what ever the user chooses. i am a beginner but i think it has something to do with the fact that i'm trying to pass a dynamic array whose parameters are defined by the user, but that just a guess. please help, i errors get like these

```
matrix2.C:15:11: error: invalid operands of types ‘int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)a) + -1)) + 1)][(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)b) + -1)) + 1)]’ and ‘int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)c) + -1)) + 1)][(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)d) + -1)) + 1)]’ to binary ‘operator*’
  cour<<m1*m2;
```

or

```
$ g++ matrix.C -omatrixs -lm
matrix.C: In function ‘int main()’:
matrix.C:16:25: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
```

and here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
//Prototypes
double Matrixsettings(int&, int&, int&, int&);
int Matrixinputs(int&, int &);

int main()
{
    int a=2, b=2, c=2, d=2;
    cout<<  Matrixsettings( a,b,c,d);
    cout<< a<<b<<c<<d;
    int m1 [a] [b], m2 [c] [d];
    cout<<m1 [a] [b]<< m2 [c] [d];
    int Matrixinputs(m1 [a] [b],m2 [c] [d]);
return 0;
}

double Matrixsettings( int &a, int &b,  int &c, int &d)
{ 
    cout<< "how many rows in the first matrix: ";
    cin>> a;
    cout<< "how many columns in the first matrix: ";
    cin>> b;
    cout<< "how many rows in the second matrix: ";
    cin>> c;
    cout<< "how many columns in the second matrix: ";
    cin>> d;
    return 0;
}

int Matrixinputs(m1& [a] [b],m2& [c] [d]);
{
//this function will have a loop with cout and cin line defining each input of the matrix like array array
}
```

Comment: C++ hasn't VLAs. Just use `vector<vector<int> >`.

Comment: how would i implement this? sorry i quite clueless. i probably taking a vary odd and round about way to write a simple program that multiplies two mathematical matrices defined by the user and returns an error if the matrices can not be multiplied.

Comment: Again, instead of trying to use VLAs, use a vector of vectors. You can index them as if they were primitive arrays.

Comment: thanks for help. i completely understand this conceptually but i looks like I'm going figure out how to implement it syntactically.

Comment: `vector<vector<int> > matrix;` is how you declare a vector of vectors of `int`. If you are having trouble with such syntax, you'd be better off reading a beginner C++ book instead of already trying to do rather involved things like matrix multiplication.

Comment: lol i actually am reading a beginner C++ book for my beginner 100 level programing class. but it is hilarious to know how obvious it is that i am a complete and utter beginner.

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't know you are actually in the process of reading such a book. Keep continuing. (There are too many people around here who think that programming knowledge can be achieved without learning the language, but merely by asking trivial questions on SO -- and unfortunately, this is only getting worse, so excuse me of my false assumption.)

Comment: no problem i was not insulted or anything just found it funny. this program i'm writing is an assignment for that class. and after an hour or two of being stuck at the same part i generally post a question on this site where some one like your self point out something that is obviously wrong with what i'm doing and off on my merry way

Answer (score 1):

```
void Matrixinputs(int* matrix, int row, int column);
{
//this function will have a loop with cout and cin line defining each input of the matrix like array array

for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<column; j++)
    {
        cin >> matrix[i*row+column];
    }
}
}
```

Outside this function, manually alocate memory to the matrix pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use a vector, but an example of using new.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T **make_2d(int r, int c){
    T** array_2d = new T*[r];
    for(int i=0;i<r;++i)
        array_2d[i] = new T[c];
    return array_2d;
}

template <typename T>
void drop_2d(T** matrix, int r){
    for(int i=0;i<r;++i)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;
}

typedef int** Matrix;

void MatrixInputs(Matrix &m, int r, int c){
    for(int i = 0;i < r; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < c;++j){
            cout << "[" << i << "][" << j << "] >";
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int a,b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    Matrix m = make_2d<int>(a, b);

    MatrixInputs(m, a, b);

    //print
    for(int i=0;i<a;++i){
        cout << "[ " ;
        for(int j=0;j<b;++j){
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "]" << endl;
    }
    drop_2d(m, a);
}
```